# Using generics as a java method access modifier

Tags: java, generics

In this [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/example/MethodSpy.java)

What does this method signature mean?

```
<E extends RuntimeException> void genericThrow() throws E
```

I was expecting to see something like public, private etc in place of the `<E extends RuntimeException>`

Comment: That's a [Generic Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

Comment: The lack of an access modifier makes it package private.

Comment: 'Default' scope (package-rpivate), generic type E which extends RuntimeException, void return type, named 'genericThrow' which throws an exception of type E.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible for this method to have an access modifier; it just doesn't have one.  That means that it is package-private.

```
public <E extends RuntimeException> void genericThrow() throws E
private <E extends RuntimeException> void genericThrow() throws E
protected <E extends RuntimeException> void genericThrow() throws E
```

The `<E extends RuntimeException>` declares a generic type parameter called `E` with an upper bound.  That is, `E` must be `RuntimeException` or a subclass.

Comment: Thanks. But what is the use of generic method. From the oracle docs, i am not able to understand what type checking is enforced by making the method generic. In our example, it means that the method can only throw an exception that is a subclass of RuntimeException? I was thinking it should be written as: void genericThrow() throws <E extends RuntimeException>

Comment: For a method that can throw any `RuntimeException`, generics aren't necessary.  `void genericThrow() throws RuntimeException` will suffice.  Making the exception generic here doesn't really help, because you can't say `throw new E()`.  You can also just say `catch (RuntimeException e)` when calling the method to catch them all anyway.

Comment: why cant we say:void genericThrow() throws <E extends RuntimeException>

Comment: You can only refer to any generic type parameters in scope there; for generic methods, you must declare any generic type parameters before the return type.